# What is the source of Meteor 1.5 updgrade Error with imports, and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, meteor

Having issues with the new release of Meteor 1.5

After upgrading an existing Meteor app the following errors were thrown
[(Original Post on Meteor forums)](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-5-update-imports-promise-server-error-on-build/36905/5)

```
=> Started proxy.                                                                        
/Users/<user>/.meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.12.3_1.ph1kh6++os+web.browser+web.cord
ova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-pro
mise/promise_server.js:190                                                               
      throw error;                                                                       
      ^                                                                                  

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined                                     
    at assertPath (path.js:8:11)                                                         
    at Object.posix.relative (path.js:496:3)
```

Removing all non-essential and test removing coffeescript package, the error persists. Have seen other instances of the error reported.

Comment: Did you upgrade node? what's your node version?

Comment: Found the issue was with `okgrow:analytics` package. Seems to be a very small issue of importing scope within that package. Disable/remove the package and the problem goes away.